# How can I revive this game?

Tags: actionscript-3

My AS3 code:

```
   
   public class PHPConnect extends EventDispatcher
   {
      
      public static const DATA_LOADED:String = "phpLoaded";
      
      public static const RETURN_XML:String = "returnXML";
      
      public static const RETURN_VARS:String = "returnVars";
       
      
      private var variables:URLVariables;
      
      private var request:URLRequest;
      
      private var loader:URLLoader;
      
      private var phpContent:Object;
      
      public function PHPConnect(param1:String, param2:String = "returnVars")
      {
         var isActive:int;
         var vars:String = param1;
         var type:String = param2;
         super();
         isActive = MyStar.userActive ? 1 : 0;
         variables = new URLVariables(vars + "&usession=" + Globals.sessionId + "&useractive=" + isActive);
         request = new URLRequest();
         loader = new URLLoader();
         request.url = "https://profligate-contrast.000webhostapp.com/mystar.php";
         request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
         request.data = variables;
         if(type == PHPConnect.RETURN_VARS)
         {
            loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
         }
         loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler);
         try
         {
            loader.load(request);
         }
         catch(error:Error)
         {
            trace("Unable to load URL");
         }
      }
      
      private function completeHandler(param1:Event) : void
      {
         phpContent = param1.target.data;
         dispatchEvent(new Event(PHPConnect.DATA_LOADED));
      }
      
      public function get loadContent() : Object
      {
         return phpContent;
      }
   }
}
```

My PHP Code

```
<?php
       echo "usession=1&done=true";    
       echo "useractive=1&done=true";
?>
```

I was reviving a old game from 2011 by modifying the source of the game using JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler known as MyStar. The servers of the game has been shutdown a long time ago. Does anyone knows how to fix? The request url was:
https://alienearths.org/mystar/mystar.php

Comment: Basically without the game server such games were almost nothing. You seem to not have access to server-side code, so likely your efforts are doomed.